# Performance Impact with FileOutputStream using OpenCSV

Tags: fileoutputstream, bufferedwriter, opencsv

We are using OpenCSV

(http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html)

to write a report from a file with xml content.

There are two ways to go about this ->

i) Write using FileOutputStream

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter osr= new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
writer = new CSVWriter(osr);
```

ii) Write using BufferedWriter

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
writer = new CSVWriter(out);
```

Does anybody know how the performance of the writing of this report gets affected by choosing one option over another ?

To my understanding OpenCSV does not care as long as it gets a stream that it can use.

The *delta* (difference) in performance would be the step before it, where the outputstream is created from the file.

What is the performance impact of using **OutputStreamWriter** versus **BufferedWriter** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running some benchmarks with Google [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/), it appears that the BufferedWriter option is the fastest (but there's really not much of a difference, so I'd just use the option that you're comfortable with).

How to interpret results:

- The `FileOutputStreamWriter` scenario corresponds with option i
- The `BufferedWriter` scenario corresponds with option ii
- The `FileWriter` scenario is one I added which just uses a plain old FileWriter.

Each benchmark was run 3 times: writing 1000, 10,000, and 100,000 rows.

The tests were run on Linux Mint, i5-2500k (1.6GHz) CPU, 8GB RAM, with Oracle JDK7 (writing to a SATA green HDD). Results would vary with a different setup, but this should be good for comparison purposes.

```
  rows              benchmark     ms linear runtime
  1000 FileOutputStreamWriter   6.10 =
  1000         BufferedWriter   5.89 =
  1000             FileWriter   5.96 =
 10000 FileOutputStreamWriter  50.55 ==
 10000         BufferedWriter  50.71 ==
 10000             FileWriter  51.64 ==
100000 FileOutputStreamWriter 525.13 =============================
100000         BufferedWriter 505.05 ============================
100000             FileWriter 535.20 ==============================
```

FYI opencsv wraps the `Writer` you give it in a `PrintWriter`.